# SQL Server Query: Using JOIN to include NULL values

Tags: sql, join, null, sql-server-2012

I need help with the following SQL Server query where the columns a.TAProfileID and c.CountryCode have "NULL" values in the database.

I want my JOIN statements to return "NULL" values where they exist.

```
SELECT 
a.ReservationStayID AS 'Reservation Id',
a.PMSConfirmationNumber as 'PMS No',
a.CreatedOn AS 'Date Created',
a.ArrivalDate AS 'Date of Arrival',
a.DepartureDate AS 'Date of Departure',
a.TAProfileID AS 'TA Id',
a.StatusCode AS 'Status',
b.PropertyCode AS 'Hotel',
c.Name AS 'Travel Agency',
c.CountryCode AS 'Market Code',
d.CountryName AS 'Mkt'

FROM ReservationStay a

inner JOIN GuestStaySummary b ON a.ReservationStayID = b.ReservationStayID
inner JOIN TravelAgency c ON a.TAProfileID = c.TravelAgencyID
inner JOIN Market d ON c.CountryCode = d.CountryCode
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In order to return or produce `NULL` values you will have to use `LEFT JOIN`s.

So, your query should be something like:

```
SELECT 
     a.ReservationStayID AS 'Reservation Id'
    ,a.PMSConfirmationNumber AS 'PMS No'
    ,a.CreatedOn AS 'Date Created'
    ,a.ArrivalDate AS 'Date of Arrival'
    ,a.DepartureDate AS 'Date of Departure'
    ,a.TAProfileID AS 'TA Id'
    ,a.StatusCode AS 'Status'
    ,b.PropertyCode AS 'Hotel'
    ,c.NAME AS 'Travel Agency'
    ,c.CountryCode AS 'Market Code'
    ,d.CountryName AS 'Mkt'
FROM ReservationStay a
    INNER JOIN GuestStaySummary b ON a.ReservationStayID = b.ReservationStayID
    LEFT JOIN TravelAgency c ON a.TAProfileID = c.TravelAgencyID
    LEFT JOIN Market d ON c.CountryCode = d.CountryCode
```

Comment: Outer joins do not use existing NULL values for matching. They produce NULL values when a match doesn't exist.